# Splitting the prices (Number values £s) from within the text?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table column (df1['income']), shown below, and I want to extract just the first prices.

| Income |
| --- |
| Approx £1,000000 £2 psf |
| £1,000,050 £4psf |
| £15000000 £3psf |
| Expected £520000 £3.2 psf |

```
df1['Income'].str.split(r'\£.........',)
```

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\£.........')
matches = pattern.finditer(str(df1['Income']))

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

The issue is the first code extracts both prices and the second code removes all the characters, rather than splitting them how I'd want.

All help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you provided is a real representation of you real data, you can use [`rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) on the 2nd occurrence of `£` symbol, and get the second element of each list `str[1]`:

```
df['1st_price'] = df.Income.str.rsplit('£',2).str[1].str.replace(',','').astype(int)

>>> df
                      Income  1st_price
0    Approx £1,000000 £2 psf    1000000
1           £1,000,050 £4psf    1000050
2            £15000000 £3psf   15000000
3  Expected £520000 £3.2 psf     520000
```